# TS2307: Cannot find module '~express/lib/express'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm converting a working JavaScript file to TypeScript.

I use Express in this file, so I've added the following to the top of the file:

```
///<reference path="./typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />

import {Request} from "~express/lib/express";
```

But the second line produces an error:

> TS2307: Cannot fine module '~express/lib/express'

I've installed the typings of express, so I actually didn't wrote those two lines by myself, but WebStorm auto generated them by clicking "alt + enter", so I would expect it to work. Unfortunately I get that error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install the typings? `npm install @types/express`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the script reference path was to "node" rather than to "express":

```
///<reference path="./typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />
```

So this has fixed it:

```
///<reference path="./typings/modules/express/index.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this line

`import * as express from "express";`

it was taken from http://brianflove.com/2016/03/29/typescript-express-node-js/

hope it helps you.

Comment: It produces the same error: "TS2307: Cannot fine module 'express'", but thanks for trying.